# pass address of an object to another object C++

Tags: c++, reference

```
int main(){

  Test obj1(a,b,c);

  Test obj2(d,e,f);

  &obj1=&obj2;//This line wont work saying lvalue required on left side

}
```

What can i do to counter this error? I want to store address of obj2 into obj1 so their member variables become same(a=d,b=e,c=f) and when i change a member variable of obj1, it changes in obj2 aswell.

Comment: Using obj1=obj2 doesnt helps because when i change value of obj1 member variables, it doesnt changes the member variables of obj2

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to make `obj1` to be a reference of `obj2` (so `obj1` and `obj2` are *the same* object)?

Comment: That's about the same as writing `7500 = 4344;`

Comment: What should `&obj1 = &obj2;` mean or do?

Comment: Pointers and references concepts should be explained in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In short, you cannot do that - `obj1` and `obj2` are now declared as two separate objects and you cannot change their type. You can however create a reference for any of those of those objects, and changes made through reference will affect original object.

Comment: Yes i want to make obj1 a reference of obj2 but not at the time of declaration i.e Test& obj1=obj2;

Comment: @HuzaifaImran Not possible. Reference variable must be initialized at declaration. You can use pointer variable as the answer suggests.

Comment: Then perhaps pointers. But I still wonder what the *actual* problem you try to solve might be? Perhaps there are other solutions that doesn't require pointers? I also recommend you think about ownership semantics, who owns the object `obj2`? Should you perhaps be using e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or raw non-owning pointers?

Comment: Your edit leaks memory - the first Test object is allocated but never used, and cannot be freed.

Comment: @interjay please don't include solution in the answer. You should instead accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @interjay i did not write my whole program here, just a glimpse of it. In my actual program, i am using the first Test object otherwise there would be no point of not declaring the first Test object as a reference directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is like `42 = 64`. It makes no sense. If you want to store the address of an object, you can use a pointer object:

```
Test obj1;
Test obj2;

Test * pobj = &obj1; // pointing to obj1
pobj = &obj2; // pointing to obj2
```

You could also use a reference to accomplish something similar, but since you mentioned you want to be able to rebind to a different object after the declaration, pointers are a better fit for your use case.

Comment: "since you mentioned you want to be able to rebind to a different object after the declaration, pointers are a better fit for your use case." I mildly to strongly disagree. If you use C++ then use C++. If you need to rebind then `std::reference_wrapper` is the solution imho.

Comment: @bolov pointers are a part of C++. `reference_wrapper` is really a pointer wrapper.

Comment: "pointers are a part of C++." By that logic so is `goto` and `malloc` and `const char* str = new char[20]`. They part of the C++ syntax. But a part of C++ that shouldn't be used. C++ has higher level abstractions which should be used instead. I admit there are some use cases for raw pointers in C++ but they are so so few beyond working with C code and this is definitely not one of them. imho.

Comment: `reference_wrapper` is really a pointer wrapper. And `while` is really a `goto` wrapper.

Comment: @bolov while all of those things you mentioned can be abused, they all have their own valid use cases. Anything can be abused/misused. If you want a non-owning pointer, that's an entirely valid use case.

Comment: Yes, when you use raw pointers in C++ they should definitely be non-owning. But because historically pointers weren't (and tbo they still aren't to this day) used exclusively for non-owning semantics it can become confusing whether the pointer is actually non-owning or not. Add on top of that the problem of the pointer being possibly null. A `T*` can mean a plethora of things (do I need to delete it or not? can it be null?) while a reference or a `std::reference_wrapper` is a safer alternative with a more constraint clear semantics (definitely non-owning and non-null).

Comment: @bolov I disagree. Things are what you make them. If your codebase is full of smart pointers and RAII, when a raw pointer is used, it's clear that it's a non-owner. Your silence speaks there. If you're dedicated, you can use a `reference_wrapper` as an owner as in this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/yQ5cpH).

Comment: in your example the `reference_wrapper` is definitely not a owner. It does not manage the lifetime of the integer and you have a memory leak. "If your codebase is full of smart pointers and RAII, when a raw pointer is used, it's clear that it's a non-owner. " yes, if you have such a clean codebase then definitely yes. "I disagree" you can and you certainly have a point. But I will remain on my opinion that a higher abstraction with a narrower semantics is better.

Answer (score 2):

> so their member variables become same(a=d,b=e,c=f) and when i change a member variable of obj1, it changes in obj2 aswell.

What you want is not pointers or addresses. What you describe is a reference:

```
Test obj1(a,b,c);

Test& obj2 = obj1;
```

If you want to be able to rebind the reference then use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
Test obj1(a,b,c);
Test obj1b(d,e,f);

auto obj2 = std::ref(obj1);
obj2 = obj1b;
```

Comment: Well, [not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611610/pass-address-of-an-object-pass-another-object-c/61611724#comment108983823_61611610)

Comment: @Ayxan yes exactly this. I see the same problem over and over again. The OP has a problem X and in solving this problem he/she thinks needs to implement Y so asks primarily about Y while mentioning X in passing. People then race to solve Y without stopping to think if the OP really needs Y. In this case `X` is paragraph I quote and Y is the question about pointers and adresses.

Comment: OP never mentioned pointers in the question. The question states "I want to store address of obj2 into obj1" and a comment mentions some constraint.

Comment: @Ayxan "I want to store address of obj2 into obj1` that is the Y in the XY problem.

Comment: Thank you for raising my awareness about rebindable reference wrapper objects.  I've seen them used in template metaprogramming, and hadn't investigated more deeply at that time, hence I hadn't realized their general applicability.